# What is the latest Android SDK update for Delphi 10.2.3 and where do I find it to install?

Tags: delphi-10.2-tokyo

I am using Delphi 10.2.3 Enterprise version and Android SDK 24.3.3 32 bit is installed. Where can I find the info telling me which latest Android version is still supported by Delphi 10.2.3 Enterprise.Also, where can I find the Android to download it. I could find the procedure how to add an SDK into my Delphi. Please help?

Comment: It is probably in the release notes. Not sure for the old version you use, but current version has a file radstudio_readme_en_html which will redirect to the online release notes. The documentation is the first location you have to look at!

Comment: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Adding_an_Android_SDK Delphi 10.3 added support for API 26, so Tokyo does not support higher than API 25.